# Opinions on NoSQL and indexing lots of data?

Tags: database, database-design, nosql

I was at a .NET development group meeting a couple weeks ago and the speaker was extolling the virtues of NoSQL and how even relational data doesn't have to be stored relationally if you just index lots of data.  So, my questions are: was he blowing smoke?  How does one craft an index to be more efficient than the last?  Does indexing just logically store the information in a table in a logical format i.e. alphabetically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well relational data is needed more for data integrity than indexing. Speed is not the only consideration when choosing a database. SQL Server and other enterpise databases can perform very well if they are designed by people who know what they are doing. Unforuntately most relational databases are designed by data amateurs and their performance reflects that.

NoSQL databases and relational database are used for different things. I would never consider putting a financial application in noSQL for instance because of the need for data integrity and internal controls to prevent fraud and ensure records are consistent and correct. However a website where data quality doesnt matter so much (think Google - who would notice if they failed to serve up every single website that mentions Bill Gates in a query) then yes it is a good choice.